# Does "Search and Rescue" works when your pet is defeated?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Does ["Search and Rescue"](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/%22Search_and_Rescue%22) works when your pet is defeated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Your downed pet will seek out a nearby player and begin to revive them.

This has minor benefits, as defeated pets will not be targetable, and so the reviving cannot be interrupted (though since pets revive much slower than players to begin with, the tactical benefit is minimal).

Comment: It's probably not meant to work this way, but since the devs hate rangers they won't fix it for ages :P

Comment: When did this happen? I never experienced that when I was using that skill. Then again, I haven't used that skill since shortly after getting it, because it's pretty rubbish.

But when I was using it, I never encountered that behaviour.